# Arduino play many piezo at once

Tags: arduino-mega, piezo

I need to play sound on 10 piezos at once. How to do that without `delay()` function.

Comment: You could use the millis() function of your Arduino...

Comment: @Fusseldieb post example please

Comment: Use the blink-without-delay pattern https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay, a TimeMarker https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Timemark or a Scheduler https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Timer library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer).

You can attach up to 10 events to each `Timer` object you declare. That will suit your use case.

Comment: Post a code please.

Comment: Why this code not work? `long ids[10];
void playNote(int pin, unsigned long freq) {
  int ms = 1000/freq;
  ids[pin] = t.oscillate(pin, ms / 2, HIGH);
}

void stopNote(int pin) {
  t.stop(ids[pin]);
}`

Comment: Post a new question with your full code and not just a snippet, You'll get much better help. I'll also participate.